# Magento 2 :- how to get email address in sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before events

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, event-observer, custom-options

How to get email address in sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before events    guest user email address.

```
<?php namespace xxxxxx\xxxx\Observer; 

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

class Observer implements ObserverInterface { 

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address
 */
protected $customerAddressHelper;



/**
 * Initialize dependencies.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $customerAddressHelper
 */

public function __construct(


      \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $customerAddressHelper

) { 
   $this->customerAddressHelper = $customerAddressHelper;


}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment */
    $shippingAssignment = $observer->getShippingAssignment();
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address */
    $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();

     $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();


    $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
    $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP. '/var/log/nitesh.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($address->getTelephone()); 
    $logger->info($address->getFirstname()); 
    $logger->info($address->getLastname()); 
    $logger->info($address->getEmail()); 
    $logger->info($quote->getCustomerEmail()); 

}
```

> print in a log file is :
>  2019-08-07T07:04:44+00:00 INFO (6):
>   7827495597
>  2019-08-07T07:04:44+00:00 INFO (6): testasd
>   2019-08-07T07:04:44+00:00 INFO (6): test1
>   2019-08-07T07:04:44+00:00 INFO (6):
>  2019-08-07T07:04:44+00:00 INFO
>   (6):

Email address is empty. I want to get guest user email address in custom observer file .

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: **$email=$customer->getEmail();** empty print , not get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get guest customer email by using following

```
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

$logger->info($shippingAddress->getEmail());
```

**Hope this solution works for you**

Comment: Thanks, but **$logger->info($shippingAddress->getEmail());** empty print , not working for me

Comment: Do you get result array of $shippingAddress?

Comment: result array of $shippingAddress is empty

Comment: <event name="sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before">
        <observer name="guest_sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before" instance="xxxx\xxx\Observer\Observer"/>
    </event>

Comment: using this event in my events file

Comment: Try to print  $quote->getCustomerEmail() after $quote = $observer->getQuote();

Comment: already print **$quote->getCustomerEmail() after $quote = $observer->getQuote();** in my code ,but not working

Comment: I think your observer is not calling. Check by printing something just after starting of execute() function.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$logger->info($address->getEmail());
```

use this  line

```
$logger->info($order->getCustomerEmail());
```

Comment: this event call before going to the payment section, so the order is not created.

Comment: you use like this $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); in your code you get the order info in that variable?